# Log event datetime with.Net Core Console logger

Tags: datetime, logging, .net-core

I'm using logging to Console output, that built-in to .Net Core framework.
Here initialization of the logger:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory()
                    .AddConsole());
```

Also for logging I'm using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtension`s class with methods `Log...`
Here an example of logging in my App:

```
_logger.LogInformation(eventId, "Action is started.");
```

Where `_logger` is instance of `ILogger<T>` class and initialized in the class constructor with built-in dependency injection.
As result of calling of the above method Console output shows following string:

```
info: NameSpaceName.ClassName[eventId] Action is started.
```

I would like to display date-time in the Console output, that points to time, when the Log method is executed, but it seems that Log.. methods don't contain any methods that allow to display date time.

Does it exist some method or additioanl classes-formatters that allow to display the action datetime in console output without passing it to the method as part of the message?

Comment: In NetCore 3.0 there will be a configuration for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Built-in .NET Core console logger doesn't log date-time. Track [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/483) to get more details. The easiest workaround is:

```cs
logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, 1, someObj, null, (s, e) => DateTime.Now + " " + s.ToString());
```

I wrote a [custom console logger](https://github.com/ilya-chumakov/LoggingAdvanced) to automatically log the timestamp and do other useful tricks:

```
[2017.06.15 23:46:44] info: WebHost[1]      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6002/hc
```

Comment: Thank you. Your library is brilliant. I've just added link to Nuget package, removed references to standard Logging libraries, updated initialization and it works as expected/

Answer (score 51):

The feature was added into version 3 of the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console)(here is the [pr](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/pull/911)). You can activate this with setting the `TimestampFormat`:

```cs
  new ServiceCollection()
     .AddLogging(opt =>
     {
         opt.AddConsole(c =>
         {
            c.TimestampFormat = "[HH:mm:ss] ";
         });
    })
```

Comment: For valid format strings, see [`DateTime.ToString(string? format)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring)

Comment: In .NET 5, this has been deprecated. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter

Comment: @StefHeyenrath the deprecation is for ***`ConsoleLoggerFormat`*** not for the `TimestampFormat` mentioned here.

Comment: The only overload for `AddConsole` that can configure time format is obsolete .NET 5+. The docs recommend @PawelBulwan's answer below.  i.e. use `AddSimpleConsole()` or other new flavor `AddJsonConsole()`, etc., not `AddConsole()` as in this answer.

Comment: Not sure why folks keep saying this overload isn't deprecated.  It specifically is for this purpose in 5+. (Why recommend the overload if it doesn't solve the OP question, if you can't set time format)?

Answer (score 24):

For ASP.NET Core, you might prefer to use configuration file `appsettings.json` over wiring it directly into the code.

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "TimestampFormat": "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] "
    }
  }
}
```

This works out of the box, provided that `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is invoked in `Program.cs`.

Comment: More info about configurations can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#set-formatter-with-configuration

Answer (score 17):

Example in .NET 5 (ASP.NET Core):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(options =>
    {
        options.AddSimpleConsole(c =>
        {
            c.TimestampFormat = "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ";
            // c.UseUtcTimestamp = true; // something to consider
        });
    });

    // ...
}
```

Output example:

```
[2020-12-13 12:55:44] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: One thing that I didn't get is that this does not modify the "Debug" log (found in Visual Studio). From VS, to see the log with timestamps, you should modify the "show output from" to the web server's logs. I don't believe there is a way to add timestamps to the debug log as AddDebug takes no arguments.

Comment: This is flagged as Depricated in .Net 5

Comment: @Matt @StefHeyenrath the deprecation is for `ConsoleLoggerFormat` not for the `TimestampFormat` mentioned here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter indeed specifies "In .NET 5, support for custom formatting was added to console logs in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console namespace."

Comment: @Adarsha Thank you for clarifying, I had accidentally done `options.AddConsole` not `options.AddSimpleConsole`