# ASP.NET Core include timestamp in all log entries

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.0 application with built-in console logging enabled. Here is the WebHost creation:

```
var webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5002")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

webHost.Run();
```

When sending an HTTP POST request, the following log messages are generated and showed in the Console stdout:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5002/api/sample application/json 2144
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
  Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.SampleController.Post (Model.Solve) with arguments (MyApp.Request.MyRequest) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
  Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
  Executed action MyApp.Controllers.SampleController.Post (MyApp) in 1201.9411ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
  Request finished in 1446.1907ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

As a requirement for going in production, I need all log entries to include a timestamp: now, I know I could provide the timestamp myself when calling the Log() method as explained in [this open issue on the GitHub ASP.NET Logging repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/483), however how am I supposed to do so on log messages generated by the WebHost directly (like the ones showed above)?
Is there a way to add the timestamp without having to rewrite a complete custom Logger as in the solution proposed in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434653/log-event-datetime-with-net-core-console-logger)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a third-party solution is the right answer.

As [explained](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/483#issuecomment-320574792) in the same github discussion you linked about the built-in logging:

> This really is a logging abstraction, the default sinks are very extremely basic and usually farm out to other systems to get more features.

and

> There are so many amazing 3rd party logging systems with richer features than what we will ever provide OOTB. I'd recommend you use those in your production applications.

I would strongly recommend (also in the github issue) that you consider a well-maintained structured-logging package like [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog).

I'm sure the custom code you linked is probably fine, but Serilog has many contributors and you can be sure it'll be up-to-date well into the future. The main page will link you to extensions specific to ASP.NET Core logging. (I don't have any vested interest in the product, but I do use it, it's quite easy to set up and use, and is very flexible.)

Structured logging lets you add arbitrary JSON data to your logs, which is a huge benefit during troubleshooting over simple "write a string of text" logging like we used to do.

Answer (score 20):

As indicated in the linked question, this feature is now built-in to the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console. You can activate it by setting the TimestampFormat:

```cs
  new ServiceCollection()
     .AddLogging(opt =>
     {
         opt.AddConsole(c =>
         {
            c.TimestampFormat = "[HH:mm:ss] ";
         });
    })
```

Comment: For all builtin options in .NET 5 see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter
Adding timestamps can now also be done via appsettings.json.

Comment: As Grimm's comment is accurate, further information on formatting is also available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231223/1548275